# Seeing how many times a user clicked on an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to count the number of times a user has clicked on any image. This is what I have come up with:

```
    var count = 0

   $('document').ready(function() {
        function countClicks() {
            $('img').click(function() {
                count++;
            }
        )};
    )};
```

I am wondering if this will even work and if it is the best approach to my solution. Also, how I would access the 'count' for later? For example, if I were to put in a basic conditional that checked if 'count' was greater than 10, would it be a separate function or would it be within the 'countClicks' function? Thank you and sorry if this question it overly simple.

Comment: Do you need to count number of clicks on each image or on all images in total?

Comment: You do not need to wrap the click handler in a function (in this case, `countClicks()`), and if you want to keep track of the clicks across many page loads and visitors, you will need to store that in a database.

Comment: I just need to keep track of any time the user has clicked on an any image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) storage:

```
$('img')
    .data('counter', 0)
    .click(function() {
        var counter = $(this).data('counter');
        $(this).data('counter', counter + 1);
    });
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/QEKMf/

Answer (score 0):

You should try considering the persist the count value(in database) if you want to retrieve the value for later use.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Event Listeners is a good practice** instead of onClick. Here's, a **simple way** of doing it. JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xomkq7dv/3/

```
document.getElementById ("cat").addEventListener ("click", updateCounter, false);
    var count = 0;
    function updateCounter() {
        count++;  
        document.getElementById("counted").innerHTML = "This has been clicked " + count + " times.";
    }
```